# I want to test specific emit name is called?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, karma-jasmine, sinon

I coding unit test for vue with `karma` . I can check `emit is trigger(called)` by below code !

test.spec.js

```
let stub = sinon.spy(vm, "$emit")
vm.save()
expect(stub.called).toBeTruthy()
```

test.vue

```
methods: {
  save() {
    this.$emit('edit-field', true);
    this.close()
  },
  close() {}
}
```

But I want to check `specific emit` trigger , I tried like below but not working ...

```
let stub = sinon.spy(vm, "$emit('edit-field')") //getting error 
stub = sinon.spy(vm, "$emit::edit-field") //getting error also
vm.save()
expect(stub.called).toBeTruthy()
```

Comment: I don't know why one of answerer have deleted his post . I can improve my test code a lot now because of his answer . May be he don't getting my updated comment but I can accept his answer as a solve one .....

Comment: Did you solve this yet?

Comment: Yes! I solved it

Comment: If your solution is sufficiently different from the proposed answers (or, they did actually help but they needed more), you are welcome to add your solution as a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

- check emit name

```html
it(' -> edit function', () => {
    let stub = sinon.stub(vm, '$emit')
    stub.callsFake(name => {
     expect(name).toBe('edit-field')
    })
    vm.close()
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

With official `@vue/test-utils` you can do something like this:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'

const wrapper = shallowMount(Component)
wrapper.vm.save();
expect(wrapper.emitted()['edit-field'].length).toBe(1);
expect(wrapper.emitted()['edit-field'][0]).toEqual([true]);
```

From [docs](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/common-tips.html#asserting-emitted-events).